# How to count how many types in array[Any]

Tags: arrays, swift, types, switch-statement, any

I am new to Swift so im just trying to solve basic problems, but can't figure out this one.

I am trying to count how many times a String, Int, Double or another class appears. And output the data. Right now i am only outputting the type. This is the code so far:

```
var myArr = [Any]()

myArr.append("hello")
myArr.append("goodbye")
myArr.append(1)
myArr.append(1.0)
myArr.append(Student())

for item in myArr {
    switch item {
    case let stringy as String :
        print(stringy, type(of: stringy))
    case let inty as Int :
        print(type(of: inty))
    case let doubly as Double :
        print(type(of: doubly))
    case let student as Student :
        print(type(of: student))
    default:
        print("unknown object")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to `group` the array to a dictionary by the type *description*

```
var myArr = [Any]()

myArr.append("hello")
myArr.append("goodbye")
myArr.append(1)
myArr.append(1.0)
myArr.append(Student())

let typeData = Dictionary(grouping: myArr, by: {String(describing:type(of: $0))})

// -> ["Student": [__lldb_expr_9.Student()], "Double": [1.0], "Int": [1], "String": ["hello", "goodbye"]]
```

and print the result, the `key` and the number of items in `value`

```
for (key, value) in typeData {
    print("\(key): \(value.count)" )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you can make a value `storeCount` to store value each team it match in each `switch case`

But the thing is that is not the good way to do that. You can split the array into subarray which each array match a type then you can easily to deal with value later.

Using `filter` to filter from beginning array each value  which match with condition ( here is type given). If right type than get value.

```swift
let stringArr = myArr.filter {
    $0 as? String != nil
}
let intArr = myArr.filter {
    $0 as? Int != nil
}
let doubleArr = myArr.filter {
    $0 as? Double != nil
}
let studentArr = myArr.filter {
    $0 as? Student != nil
}
```

Usage

```swift
print("value string: ", stringArr, "; count: ", stringArr.count) // value string:  ["hello", "goodbye"] ; count:  2
print("value int: ", intArr, "; count: ", intArr.count) // value int:  [1] ; count:  1
print("value double: ", doubleArr, "; count: ", doubleArr.count) // value double:  [1.0] ; count:  1
print("value student: ", studentArr, "; count: ", studentArr.count) // value student:  [SelectText.Student] ; count:  1
```